# Finding the span of $AB=0 $ if I have the basis of $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the basis of a kernel of a matrix $A\in M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb R)$, or the basis of $Ax=0$, suppose the given basis of the kernel is $v_1,v_2$. How can I find the span of $W$ such that $W= \{ B\in M_{4\times 2}(\mathbb R)|AB=0\} $ ?

(I have an example with numbers for the given basis and the matrix $A$ but I would prefer a general solution if it's not a problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the matrix $A$, noting $\ker(A) = \text{span}(v_1,v_2)$.  Let $B$ be a matrix such that $AB = 0$.

It follows that for all $x$, $A(Bx) = (AB)x = 0$.  So, $Bx \in \ker(A)$ for every $x$, so the image of $B$ is a subset of the kernel of $A$ if $B \in W$.

Now, suppose $B$ is an arbitrary matrix such that the image of $B$ is in the kernel of $A$.  It follows that for all $x$, we have $(AB)x = A(Bx) = 0$.  Since $(AB)x = 0$ for all $x$, $AB$ must be the zero matrix, so that $B \in W$ if its image is in the kernel of $A$.

So, $W$ is exactly the set of matrices whose image is contained in the kernel of $A$.  That is, $W$ is the set of matrices whose columns are of the form $\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2$ for $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm{Im}(B)\subset \mathrm{span}(v1,v2)$ So every column of $B$ must be of the form $av_1+bv_2$.
A Basis of the subspace is therfore given by the matrices $(v_1~0~0~0),(v_2~0~0~0),(0~v_1~0~0),\dots$

Comment: Every column of $B\neq be$. why is the image of $B$ the span of the kernel ?

Comment: indeed it should have been subset to make sense

Comment: You have a typo there, you wrote be instead of $B$ and OK still why is that ?

Comment: $AB=0$ so if there is an element $x$ which $B$ doesnt map to $\mathrm{span}(v_1,v_2)$, then  $A(Bx)\neq 0$ since $Bx$ is not in the kernel, and thus $AB \neq 0$

Comment: I don't understand why this implies that the image of $B$ is a subset of the kernel.

Comment: the asumtion that there exists an element $x\in \mathrm{Im}(B) $ and $x\not\in \mathrm{span}(v_1,v_2)=\ker(A)$ lead to a contradiction because $Ax=0$ but $x$ is not in the kernel and thus $\mathrm{Im}(B)\subset\mathrm{span}(v_1,v_2)$